# Golang: Use string.join on a type alias for a string

Tags: go

I have a type alias for string like

type SpecialScopes string

and I want to Join an array of this type using the strings.Join function

```
func MergeScopes(scopes ...SpecialScopes) SpecialScopes {
    return strings.Join(scopes, ",")
}
```

But with the above I get the errors

```
cannot use scopes (type []SpecialScopes) as type []string in argument to strings.Join
cannot use strings.Join(scopes, ",") (type string) as type SpecialScopes in return argument
```

Is there a way to make golang realize that SpecialScopes is just another name for strings and do the join function on it?
If not what is the most efficient way to go about doing this? One way I see is to cast all the elements in the array to string, join, then cast it back to SpecialScopes and return the value

Update 1:
I have a working implementation that casts the values. Any suggestions for a faster way to do this?

```
func MergeScopes(scopes ...SpecialScopes) SpecialScopes {
    var s []string
    for _, scope := range scopes {
        s = append(s, string(scope))
    }

    return SpecialScopes(strings.Join(s, ","))
}
```

Comment: The answers are right for the question as posed, and of them I'd go with Yandry's since it doesn't use unsafe, but big-picture, I wouldn't worry about the speed of this operation. Chances are this isn't where your app spends most of the time, and even within this function the alloc to build the combined string may dwarf the cost of making the intermediate `[]string` in your sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly the fastest way without using unsafe.

```
func MergeScopes(scopes ...SpecialScopes) SpecialScopes {
    if len(scopes) == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    var (
        sep = []byte(", ")
        // preallocate for len(sep) + assume at least 1 character
        out = make([]byte, 0, (1+len(sep))*len(scopes))
    )
    for _, s := range scopes {
        out = append(out, s...)
        out = append(out, sep...)
    }
    return SpecialScopes(out[:len(out)-len(sep)])
}
```

Benchmark code: https://play.golang.org/p/DrB8nM-6ws

```
━➤ go test -benchmem -bench=.  -v -benchtime=2s
testing: warning: no tests to run
BenchmarkUnsafe-8       30000000               109 ns/op              32 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkBuffer-8       20000000               255 ns/op             128 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkCopy-8         10000000               233 ns/op             112 B/op          3 allocs/op
BenchmarkConcat-8       30000000               112 ns/op              32 B/op          2 allocs/op
```

Comment: Thanks! The analysis and comparison really helped

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using the [`unsafe`](https://godoc.org/unsafe) package:

```
func MergeScopes(scopes ...SpecialScopes) SpecialScopes {
    specialScopes := *(*[]string)((unsafe.Pointer(&scopes)))
    s := strings.Join(specialScopes, ",")
    return *(*SpecialScopes)((unsafe.Pointer(&s)))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-wsHY2eCdc

Comment: Not inaccurate, but I'm reticent to point someone at unsafe when we haven't established that it's worse to just eat the performance cost of building a `[]string` (or to eat the lines-of-code cost of doing it Yandry's way). Note, for example, if SpecialScopes changes from `string` to `[]byte` or something, this still compiles but has undefined behavior. Opinions will differ, just noting mine.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want something fast, this is the faster way in Go:

```
func MergeScopes(scopes ...SpecialScopes) SpecialScopes {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    for ix, s := range scopes {
        buffer.WriteString(string(s))
        if ix < len(scopes)-1 {
            buffer.WriteString(", ")    
        }
    }

    return SpecialScopes(buffer.String())
}
```

Full example: https://play.golang.org/p/McWjh1yxHf

I know it doesn't look nice like a simple .Join() but it's easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple type aliases and find yourself duplicating the same code you could use following ***(if you are using go 1.18 or above)***

```
package strings

import "fmt"

type String interface {
    ~string
}

func Join[s String](str []s, sep s) s {
    if len(str) == 0 {
        return ""
    }

    if len(str) == 1 {
        return str[0]
    }

    joined := str[0]
    for _, s := range str[1:] {
        joined += sep + s
    }

    return joined
}
```

The function can be called like

```
strings.Join(scopes, ",")
```